# Изменение данных конфига в Quasar проекте без перекомпиляции

Tags: vue.js, frontend, config, quasar-framework

Помогите решить задачку:

Необходимо вынести данные (URL, Название сайта, Контакты и тд) в отдельный конфиг.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно это сделать и возможно ли потом изменять эти данные без перекомпиляции?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я применил такой способ.
Все данные вынес в `config.js` и положил его в `/src/statics` директорию.

Синтаксис `config.js` примерно такой:

```
const config = {
  Api: "ApiUrl.api/api"
  SiteName: "MySite",
  ...
}
```

Далее подключаем это файл в `/src/index.template.html` как обычный скрипт.

```
<head>
  ...
  <script type="text/javascript" src="statics/config.js"></script>
</head>
```

Теперь из любого места кода можно использовать переменные нашего конфига, например так.

```
this.$axios(config.Api + "/SomePath", ...)
```

Есть ещё нюансы с тем что бы при перекомпиляции на браузерах сбрасывался старый конфиг в кеше. Пример как это реализовано можно посмотреть в GitHub/[SunEngine/Client](https://github.com/sunengine/SunEngine/tree/master/Client).

Фишка всего метода в том, что весь конфиг не компилируется а идёт как статический файл, который лежит в `statics`, и после компиляции проекта можно изменять значения вручную в этом файле, даже на проекте в production.

Comment: Спасибо, интересный кстати вариант вынести его вообще в отдельный скрипт, я об этом даже не подумал

Comment: Как быть с несколькими релизами, если конфиг меняется от одного релиза к другому? Может в один момент произойти такой случай, что конфиг будет от нового релиза, а код от старого.

Comment: @Dmitry я у себя добавлял в конец файла конфига суффиксы config.dev.js , config.prod.js и т.п. и в коде quasar.config.js брал в зависимости от условий нужный файл

Comment: С большим бандлом и несколькими рализами в продакшене такое не пройдёт, нужно ещё добавлять хеш.

Comment: Почитай внимательнее, я про уникальность писал. У меня генерится случайная метка. Кроме того файл конфига копируется в output всегда с названием config.js , неважно сколько видов релиза.